# request.formData returns an empty object in route handler Nextjs13

Tags: next.js

So i have a form with one field (email) that runs one of my route handlers at `auth/signin` when submitted. I read the docs on form data and have just this in my `route.js` rn

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
 
export async function POST(request) {
  const formData = await request.formData()
  console.log(formData)
  return NextResponse.json({formData})
}
```

This returns an empty json object like this

```json
{
  formData : { } 
}
```

even though in my console, im pretty sure the form data is logged correctly but i cant really parse what it is, whats the Symbol(state) thing?

````js
FormData {
  [Symbol(state)]: [ { name: 'email', value: 'myemail@gmail.com' } ]
}```

So, I literally just need to extract that email from there so i can use for auth stuff. Thats all. Please help, its been hours.
````